# Spark: compute complexe statistics

Tags: apache-spark, sum, apache-spark-sql, union

I have strong statistics to compute with spark. From a dataframe, about 50 KPI must be computed (each with different filters and sum or avg...) grouped by 5 columns.

The expected result is like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 kpi1 kpi2 ... kpi50
```

I have a different request (to apply to the same dataframe) for each of the kpis. I am looking for the most optimized way to day it.

My current solution is to compute each KPI, with 0 value for other kpi, like

```
    df1.filter(...).select("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", lit(1) as "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4""kpi1").sum("kpi1").groupBy().withColumn("kpi2", lit(0)).withColumn("kpi3", ....

df2.filter....
```

then performing a union of the resulting df, then groupby and sum like

```
df1.union(df2).union(...).groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4").sum()
```

But it seems to me like a common problem. Is there a kind of pattern to do it with spark, or a better solution ?

Comment: Can you elaborate with some code?

Comment: Edited my question to add code

Comment: A combination of withColumn() and a user defined function (udf) does not work for you? can you give an example of a KPI and why you can't do it with these tools?